# Finding a point on triangle.

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, coordinate-systems

I have a non-right triangle with known x,y coordinates. Lets say A,B,C is the points of triangle. I want to find a new point D which is perpendicular line from point B and lies on the line AC. Any simpled questions for D(x,y)?

Comment: Do you mean $BD$ and $AC$ are perpendicular?

Comment: yes exactly BD and AC are perpendicular

Answer (score 1):

First, given coordinates of $A$ and $C$, you can have the formula of the line $AC$.

Secondly, we know that line $BD$ and $AC$ are perpendicular, so we can get the slope of $BD$ (the product of slopes of perpendicular lines in $\mathbb R^2$ is $-1$). With coordinates of $B$, we can then get the formula of $BD$. And $D$ is just the point of intersection of $AC$ and $BD$.

Comment: I tried this way but didn't get the right answer. I will really appreciate if you write formulas.

Comment: @user858520 What are the coordinates of $A,B,C$?

Comment: let's say A(-73.373 , 250.219) , B(119.265 , 53.673) and C(262.336, 189.630). I tried the way you told. The answer i am getting again the coordinates of point B.

Comment: @user858520 You are not doing it right then. I got the result: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+system+of+equations&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation1%22%7D+-%3E%22y%3D-%281%2F335.709%29%2861.156x-79513.571083%29%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22solve+system+of+equations%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation2%22%7D+-%3E%22y%3D%281%2F61.156%29%28335.709x-36755.907897%29%22

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct. can yoy share the equations you used.

Comment: @user858520 It's in the link. Equation 1 is the line $AC$.

Comment: can you elaborate how you took the values in equation. let's say A(x1,y1), B(x2, y2) and C(x3,y3) and slope of AC is mA and slope of BD is -1/mA.

Comment: @user858520 $mA=\frac{y_1-y_3}{x_1-x_3}$

Comment: slope is clear. But the complete equation of AC?

Comment: @user858520 You take the coordinate of either $A$ or $C$ into the equation $y=kx+b$ where $k=mA$.

Comment: what's the value of b?

Comment: @user858520 You know $y,k,x$ and you can solve for $b$......

Comment: slope of AC is is -0.096 the slope of BD is -1/-0.096. is it correct?